# Heroku git repository

Tags: git, heroku, windows-7, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to use this step in heroku:

```
This is the important step. When creating a PHP app on heroku you have to make sure you   choose the 'Cedar' Stack.

heroku create --stack cedar
The response should look something like:

Creating freezing-winter-5984... done, stack is cedar
http://freezing-winter-5984.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:freezing-winter-5984.git
**Git remote heroku added**
```

However in the terminal window I am unable to see the printed massage that says :
"Git remote heroku added"
Because of this I am unable to push to git repository. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify `--stack cedar`, it's the default.

As for no git remote added, it may be because you're not in a git repository.

Run `git init` first, so that your local directory with your app becomes a repository.

Comment: Thank you I was not running the command in the same local directory of my project